# How to display message if no errors occur in validation summary (ASP.NET)?

Tags: html, asp.net, validation

I have several textboxes, each with their own validators which errors are displayed through a validation summary whenever a Submit button is clicked. What I'm wanting to do is if you were to type something in all the textboxes and pass all the validators, when you hit the Submit button, a label or a message of some sort needs to display "Successful Entries", or something of the sort. Otherwise, if something triggers a validator, only the validation summary should display, and the "Success" message should stay hidden

Answer (score 0):

You can use modal pop up extender or some javascript function for alert message. Once success you can call that javascript function from code behind.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use ValidationSummary to display both fail and successful message. Instead, you can a panel with custom style sheet to display it.

Here is an example that use [Twitter BootStrap](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#alerts) -

[image]

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="TelerikWebDemo.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" 
href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        &nbsp;
        <div class="container">
            <asp:Panel ID="SuccessPanel" runat="server" 
                CssClass="alert alert-success" Visible="False">
                Form was submitted successfully.
            </asp:Panel>
            <div class="form-group">
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" 
                   AssociatedControlID="TextBox1">Text 1:</asp:Label>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextBox1" CssClass="form-control" />
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server"
                    ControlToValidate="TextBox1" ErrorMessage="TexBox1 is required." />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" 
                    AssociatedControlID="TextBox2">Text 2:</asp:Label>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextBox2" CssClass="form-control" />
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server"
                    ControlToValidate="TextBox2" ErrorMessage="TexBox2 is required." />
            </div>
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="Button1_Click"
                CssClass="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

### Code Behind

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsValid)
    {
        // Do something

        SuccessPanel.Visible = true;
    }
}
```